# How to search in multiple columns on yii using $criteria->compare() or $criteria->addCondition()

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

How to search in multiple columns on **yii** using `$criteria->compare()` or `$criteria->addCondition()`

I have a table named product and inside this table I have multiple columns for example: "productId, name, description..."
I need my user to be able to search in multiple columns like
`$criteria->compare('name' AND 'id' And '','' ,$search,true);` but this never works! only one column works like:
$criteria->addCondition("name LIKE '%$search%'");
or  $criteria->compare('productId',$search,true);

My search form:

```html
<div class="search-bar col-md-9 col-lg-9 no-hor-padding">
 <form role="form" onSubmit="return dosearch();" class="navbar-form- navbar-left- search-form" style="padding-left: 0;"
  action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/'); ?>" method="get">
  <input type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="<?php echo Yii::t('app','Search products'); ?>" class="search-icon form-control input-search <?php echo !empty(Yii::app()->user->id) ? "" : "sign" ?>" name="search"></input>
 </form>    
</div>
```

And my function or controller:

```
if(!empty($search)) {
    //$criteria->addCondition("name LIKE '%$search%'");
    $criteria->compare('name',$search,true);

    $searchCriteria = clone $criteria;
    $searchproducts = Products::model()->find($searchCriteria);
    if(empty($searchproducts)){
        $catrest = 1;
        $location = 1;
    }
}
```

Products::model() refer to product table
Here is the search function form model class for table "hts_products".:

```html
public function search()
 {
  // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

  $criteria->compare('productId',$this->productId);
  $criteria->compare('userId',$this->userId);
  $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
  $criteria->compare('price',$this->price);
  $criteria->compare('quantity',$this->quantity);
  $criteria->compare('sizeOptions',$this->sizeOptions,true);
  $criteria->compare('productCondition',$this->productCondition,true);
  $criteria->compare("from_unixtime(`createdDate`, '%d-%m-%Y')",$this->createdDate,true);
  //if(!empty($this->createdDate))
  //$criteria->condition = "from_unixtime(`createdDate`, '%d-%m-%Y') = '$this->createdDate'";
  //else
  //$criteria->compare('createdDate',$this->createdDate);
  /* $criteria->compare('likeCount',$this->likeCount);
  $criteria->compare('commentCount',$this->commentCount); */
  $criteria->compare('chatAndBuy',$this->chatAndBuy);
  $criteria->compare('exchangeToBuy',$this->exchangeToBuy);
  $criteria->compare('instantBuy',$this->instantBuy);
  $criteria->compare('paypalid',$this->paypalid,true);
  // $criteria->order = 'productId DESC';
  return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
  'criteria'=>$criteria,
  'pagination'=>array(
              'pageSize'=>10,
  ),
  'sort'=>array(
               'defaultOrder'=>'productId DESC',
  )

  ));
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Read this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail ?

Comment: Thank @TomaszKane for your response, but still not understand it..

Comment: looks like yii1 code not yii2, are you sure this is yii2? :)

Comment: Yes sorry for that its yii1

Comment: Thank you @Insane Skull, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

For search in multiple columns, with variables and user inputs, `compare()` could be the best option. Taken from [official Yii 1.1.x docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail):

> compare() method appends to the condition property with a new comparison
>   expression. The comparison is done by comparing a column with the
>   given value using some comparison operator.
>   Note that any surrounding white spaces will be removed from the value
>   before comparison. When the value is empty, no comparison expression
>   will be added to the search condition.

Example. In a model `Invoices`, before submit, with empty values in your search form:

```
public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('invoice_number', $this->invoice_number);
        $criteria->compare('city_id', $this->city_id);
        $criteria->compare('state', $this->state);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
}
```

It will output something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices`
```

After your submit, with all the values filled in your search form:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` 
WHERE ( invoice_number = :ycp1 AND city_id = :ycp2 AND state = :ycp3)
```

Only with `invoice_number` filled and submitted from your form. `city_id` and `state` are empty:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` 
WHERE ( invoice_number = :ycp1 )
```

You can look all [compare() method documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) to custom it as you want.

I suggest you to use `compare()` to match exact values like numbers.

For search in multiple columns with LIKE or not exact/approximated values, I suggest you to use [addSearchCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail).

Example:

```
public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('invoice_number', $this->invoice_number);
        $criteria->compare('city_id', $this->city_id);
        $criteria->compare('state', $this->state);
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('customer_name', $this->customer_name);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
}
```

It will output something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` 
WHERE ( invoice_number = :ycp1 AND city_id = :ycp2 AND state = :ycp3 AND customer_name LIKE :ycp4 )
```

If you need more code examples with `compare()` and other methods from `CDbCriteria` [you can see this nice article](http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/06/cdbcriteria-in-yii/).

Comment: Thank you @AlejandroQuiroz, I'm a real beginner! don't know how to do that in my case! I have try this:  $criteria->compare('name',$search,true); $criteria->compare('productId',$search,true);

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));    NOT working!

Comment: Please complete your question with all method controller code and search() method of your model